# MinimalOverflow - A themescript for Stack Exchange

Tags: script, style

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Screenshot of Minimalist]

### About

MinimalOverflow was written to deal with a request which Jeff Atwood put forward in the MSO Tavern on Friday, February 25, 2011. [Someone on Physics.SE asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/64697/146482) if it would be possible to get the theme changed to black on white, an inverse of the current white on black. Jeff decided it would be good to have a generic "destyled" theme for all Stack Exchange sites.

This script is my answer to Jeff's request. MinimalOverflow adds a link to the top navigation bar which allows users to toggle between any given Stack Exchange site's theme and a "clean" theme.

#### License

MinimalOverflow doesn't really have a license. Attribution is nice, but not required. (Jeff - I'll take you up on that t-shirt though. ;-D)

#### Download

You can download the usertheme by installing the user script which injects the theme switcher into the page. The user script is available on my GitHub page: [MinimalOverflow on GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MinimalOverflow). Please note that if you have installed a version prior to 0.1.5.0 then you will need to manually uninstall the old one or they will conflict.

#### Platform

MinimalOverflow should run on any browser that supports user scripts and has JavaScript enabled. It was tested in Chrome and Firefox for Mac OS X.

### Contact

This script was created by Moshe Berman. You can reach him at moshberm AT gmail. Special thanks goes to @YiJiang and @TimStone for helping with Firefox support.

### Code

The user script was written in plain old JavaScript. The stylesheet was written in CSS.
The code is available on GitHub. Feel free to fork and request a pull.

Comment: I gave it a try and it works quite well. One small suggestion though: it would be nice if the script assumed that I wanted the default theme on each site instead of the minimal theme by default. I like the way the script keeps track of each site separately though :)

Comment: thanks, finally an answer to my [feature-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/64697/146482) :)

Comment: Is there anything that can be done *not* to load the default css prior to the minimal one (thereby avoiding the flash, which is especially painful when switching from black at physics.SE)? I understand that this might not be possible due to when the script is executed (i.e. after default css is loaded) but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: @Marek - Not yet. If SO hosts it, then it can integrate better with their site engine and handle the css swapping server-side. That may or may not happen, depending on how development progresses and how the script matures. (I don't work for SOIS and I do not represent them.) I'm working out the CSS bugs and then discussing some other features with @RebeccaChernoff. Once all that happens, I can talk  to SOIS about merging it into SO.

Comment: @Moshe: so at least in principle it's possible. That's actually better than what I hoped for. By the way, thanks for putting this together in the first place.

Comment: @Marek - Yes, in principle it should be possible. The delay is caused by the site loading the first stylesheet, *then* loading the clean one off of github. That is how userscripts work. If SE integrated it, then they can generate the HTML *already* containing a reference to the clean CSS.